# How to pass a setState in a component which dynamically changes based on a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React with hooks, I have a small component that renders based on a condition.
The Recipients below component works in this way, if we have more than 1 recipient then we show a dropdown list otherwise we just show the name of the recipient.

The issue is that as you see the first is a checkbox where onChange is passing the selected recipient. Having this I mind when I have only 1 recipient I need to set that recipient in the state as  `const [recipients, setRecipients] = useState({});`

I would like to `setRecipients(...)` for when we have just 1 recipient but here I blocked and don't know the way of doing it and passing inside that component as you see is just a typography component. Need help to make this.

The onChange as per reference looks like this

```
const handleRecipientChecked = useCallback(
    id => e => {
      const selection = { ...recipients };
      selection[id].selected = !selection[id].selected;
      setRecipients(selection);
    },
    [recipients],
  );
```

The component

```
const Recipients = () => {
    return Object.keys(recipients).length > 1
      ? Object.keys(recipients).map(id => (
          <div className={classes.dropdownContainer} key={id}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  key={id}
                  checked={recipients[id].selected}
                  onChange={handleRecipientChecked(id)}
                />
              }
              label={`${recipients[id].name} (${roles[recipients[id].role]})`}
            />
          </div>
        ))
      : Object.keys(recipients).map(id => (
          <Typography>{`${recipients[id].name} (${
            roles[recipients[id].role]
          })`}</Typography>
        ));
  };
```

Comment: Just to understand this right: if there is only 1 recipient in the list, the selected property should be true permanently?
If so, can't you set selected true at the place where you receive the list in the first place?

Comment: @FlorianFankhauser yes I have to do that but I have to hide the checkbox showing only the text and I don't know how to do it. Can you show me an example of your idea?

Comment: I don't know enough of your usecase. So I guess after the user can select the recipients, there is an action where you process all selected recipients in your list. And at that point you could check if the length of the list is 1 and if so, set the selected flag of that recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you are rendering the item based on length (I.e to display checkbox or text) will be the same way you will be setting state. In your usecallback, check if the length is greater than 1 and do the normal set state for check box, while in the else block just set the state to that only item.

Comment: It is possible to see an example I cannot get this to work in any way.

Comment: Check it out here https://gist.github.com/YomiCasual/a3fae633e62639d84c5aaeded825235a